# How to join Master Detail Tables with master condition in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, join, aggregate, where-clause, lookup

How to add a condition for xads this query? (Exp: lads.status=1 )

```
db.xads.aggregate([
                {
                    $lookup: {
                        from: 'xaditems',
                        localField: '_id',
                        foreignField: 'masterId',
                        as: 'xadItems'
                    },
                }
              ]);
```

Comment: why don't you use match stage before lookup stage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works! Thanks DHIRAJ KATEKAR

```
db.xads.aggregate([
                {
                 $match:{"status":1} 
                },
                {
                    $lookup: {
                        from: 'xaditems',
                        localField: '_id',
                        foreignField: 'masterId',
                        as: 'xadItems'
                    },
                }
              ]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
db.xads.aggregate([
                {
                 $match:{"status":1} //add you filters in match
                },
                {
                    $lookup: {
                        from: 'xaditems',
                        localField: '_id',
                        foreignField: 'masterId',
                        as: 'xadItems'
                    },
                }
              ]);
```